# What is wrong with this command of mine? "ffmpeg crop and drawtext"

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have some command line to process video and it is getting some errors, can you help me to fix it?

```
@ECHO OFF
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set INPUT=D:\Shorts\code\INPUT
set OUTPUT=D:\Shorts\code\OUTPUT
:: encode video:
for %%a in ("%INPUT%\*.*") DO ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 60 -r 30 -b:v 1000k -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 48000 -metadata title="" -metadata artist="" -metadata album_artist="" -metadata album="" -metadata date="" -metadata track="" -metadata genre="" -metadata publisher="" -metadata encoded_by="" -metadata copyright="" -metadata composer="" -metadata performer="" -metadata TIT1="" -metadata TIT3="" -metadata disc="" -metadata TKEY="" -metadata TBPM="" -metadata language="eng" -metadata encoder="" -filter_complex "drawtext=text='Centered Text':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white, crop=ih*(9/16):ih" -crf 21 -c:a copy -f segment -segment_time 12 -reset_timestamps 1 -preset ultrafast "%output%\%%~na_%%03d.mp4"
pause
```

**Here is the error message**:
[image]

Comment: Add the option fontfile to drawtext e.g. `fontfile=c\:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf` (place a \ before the colon and use forward slashes in place of back slashes)

Comment: I tried with the above command line but still got the error, can you help me to fix it directly?

Comment: @Gyan : I tried with the command line above but still the error  -filter_complex "drawtext=text='Centered Text':fontfile=c\:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white, crop=ih*(9/16):ih"

Comment: Ensure the font path is correct.